# Problems using SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a game and using Javascript's SetTimeout feature. I want to track the time between each mouse movement and to do this I am using SetTimeout. The problem is that, SetTimeout is ALWAYS being called every x seconds (like SetInterval). I have been looking at this code for awhile and maybe I have misread the documentation of what SetTimeout does?

To reiterate, My goal is to measure the time between each mouse 'stoke' and it appears that SetTimeout is being called EVERY x milliseconds instead of just once. Please have a look at the code below for more information.

Again, I would like to identify a mouse 'stroke' using SetTimeout. After a mouse 'stroke' (for example a drawing of a line) there is some pause (I identified this as 25 milliseconds in this case).

```
<html>
<head>
<title> My Game </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
timeout = null;
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
    console.log(mouseX+","+mouseY);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(
        function(){alert("New Mouse Movement")
        },25);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is used to queue up a function to be executed after a specified delay. It's not intended to measure the time between two events. A single call to `setTimeout()` will cause the function you supply to be executed only once, not repeatedly every x milliseconds, but your code calls `setTimeout()` on every mousemove event. Check your console - you'll see that your `console.log()` is occurring once per timeout...

Comment: One thing you could do is capture the date into a null variable onmousemove if the variable is null, if not, then ignore it.  Then set your timeout for 25, and if there is no movement in .025 seconds, consider the mouse stopped, and then subtract now from end.

Comment: Yes, precisely however I would like to identify a mouse 'stroke' using SetTimeout. After a mouse stroke there is some pause (I identified this as 25 milliseconds in this case)

Comment: But what is a mouse "stroke" really? I mean, I could continuously move the mouse around and around in a circle for ten minutes and that would generate lots of mousemove events. **Is your real requirement to do something 25 milliseconds after the mouse stops moving?** (25ms is a really short time - if you _do_ want to do something after the mouse stops I think you'd need to use a significantly bigger delay, say 200ms.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment, just have a null time.  Then when the mouse is moved, it will set the start time and set a timer for 0.025 seconds.  If the mouse continues to move, then it will clear the timeout and start the timer over again.  If the mouse stops moving, the timeout function will fire and will log the time spent moving.

```
timeout = null;
mouseStart=null;
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    if(mouseStart===null){
        mouseStart=new Date();
    }
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
    console.log(mouseX+","+mouseY);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(
        function(){
            console.log((new Date()).getTime()-mouseStart.getTime())
            mouseStart=null;
        },25);
}
```

Fiddle, move your mouse in a circle and as soon as you stop you will get the elapsed time of mouse movement in milliseconds (+25 milliseconds):  http://jsfiddle.net/rr4g2/

**NOTE** 25 milliseconds is hella fast.  You may want something like 300 milliseconds to make it a little more clear that the mouse has stopped moving.

Comment: Thanks Tim, this is a great response.

Comment: You can probably figure out the rest to draw the stroke between start and stop :)

Answer (score 0):

You are `alert`ing a new mouse movement 25ms after it happens, not timing how long the gap is between each one. `setTimeout` is not what you need.

Instead, on each mouse movement save the current time and deduct the previous time from it, then `alert` that.

Edit: I've swapped `alert` for `console.log` since `mousemove` will run so often.

```js
var oldTime = Date.now();
document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
    console.log(mouseX+","+mouseY);
    // Get the current time.
    var newTime = Date.now();
    // Alert the difference.
    console.log('Time between mouse strokes: ' + (newTime - oldTime) + 'ms');
    // Save the current time for the next movement.
    oldTime = newTime;
};
```